# Stackdriver Analysis report unavailable error

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver

Hope someone out there using Google Cloud App Engine and Stackdriver monitoring. I got services up and running on my app engine, have been using them. Stackdriver Trace analysis provides nice daily analysis reports but its almost useless as it hits only the root ("/") ..

[image]

When I try to gather trace for a specific URI, I keep getting this error which I know 100% wrong. I got my app engine up and running and using it for sure. What am I missing here ..

[image]

Comment: Hi I am a Stackdriver product manager. Could you give an example of URI you are trying to generate report for? Does it start with a "_"?

Comment: Steren,its not public url but I'm happy to work it out thru private chat..email me at emailsahas@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The reports are automatically generated for the three most popular URLs that pass a certain threshold of traffic, so I suspect that the non-root URLs haven't had enough traffic to trigger this.

However, you can press the "New Report" button at the top of the page to generate an analysis report for any URL. You'll also be able to select the A/B comparison criteria to compare across versions of your application or different time spans. Reports typically only take a few seconds to generate.

Comment: I do have plenty of traffic for other resources. Also, if you read my question, "New Report" keeps showing me the error over and over..

Comment: Apologies, missed the second part. To confirm, are any traces available in the trace list page for the URL that you're attempting to generate a report for?